# Add new column to a QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I need to add a new column to an existing QTableWidget whenever a button is pressed, something like:

```
ui->tableWidget->addColumn();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I could find was:

```
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->count() + 1);
```

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#insertColumn : `ui->tableWidget->insertColumn(ui->tableWidget->columnCount());`

Comment: I think that there is no way better than your way. It's simple.

Comment: I'm using PyQt5 + Qt Designer, which is just a python wrapper around the C++ framework. The output of `pyuic5 tbl.ui` indicates the system uses setColumnCount and fills in missing columns, so I'd say that's the accepted method.

Answer (score 1):

```
        column_index = self.table_name.columnCount()
        self.table_name.setRowCount(1)
        self.table_name.setColumnCount(column_index + 1)

        self.tb_widget = QWidget()

        picture = "C:\\Users\\usa\\Desktop\\test.png"
        pixmap = QPixmap(picture).scaled(QSize(160, 90))
        tb_item_img = QLabel()
        tb_item_img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # tb_item_img.setFixedSize(160, 90)
        tb_item_time = QLabel()
        tb_item_time.setText("00:00:00")

        self.tb_item_btb.setProperty('time', tb_item_time.text())
        self.tb_item_btb.clicked.connect(self.clickTableCut)

        self.table_name.setColumnWidth(column_index, 160)
        self.table_name.setRowHeight(0, 90)
        self.table_name.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(column_index, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)

        self.table_name.setCellWidget(0, column_index, self.tb_widget)

        # click
        def clickTableCut(self, ):
            button = self.sender()
            if button:
                t = button.property('time')
                print(t)
                column_index = self.table_name.indexAt(button.pos()).column()
                # if remove an item
                self.table_name.removeColumn(column_index)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that code-only answers are not recommended, you can improve your answer by adding some details about the solution you provided.